# Force a window to have a top bar

Tags: gnome, window, 20.10

`figma-linux` updated today, and it removed the top bar, with the title and `- [] X` buttons.

The top bar is the only way to resize and move the window, so it needs to be there.
It happens in both maximised and windowed modes.

How can I force the window to have one, even if the application removes it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be configurable from within the app.

Look for a setting "Disable menu". Apparently it should be turned off, for the normal window decoration to show up.

See this clue: https://github.com/Figma-Linux/figma-linux/issues/127

---

By the way, you can move a window by click-dragging it *anywhere* on its entire surface, if you hold down a modifier key during the dragging. A few years back this modifier key was `Alt`, but on 20.04 it's configured by default to be the `Super` key. (This definition can be changed in the Gnome-Tweaks app, through the "Window action key" setting.)